# how to make 3 level users in laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, authentication, user-controls

I am trying to make different permission users in laravel.
but I can make only one level user by using make:auth command.
I want to make 3 level users. that is, admin, customer, guest.
They have to have different permission and different dashboard.
If you have an experience in this field, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You can try to create three different Guard for Admin, Customer, and guest check this https://github.com/sujalpatel2209/LaravelMultiUserAuthentication.

Comment: And for role and permission, you can use this https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission package.

Comment: Thank you Sujal Patel.
I will try to do that.

Comment: Maybe, you can use middleware for admin, user, and customers
https://morioh.com/p/8540ece12625